# Existence of a filtration with respect to which a sequence becomes a martingale difference.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, filtrations

Suppose $(X_t,\mathcal F_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ is such that $\mathbb E(X_t\mid \mathcal F_{t-1}) = 0$ for every $t$, where $(\mathcal F_t)$ is a filtration on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. But $(X_t)$ is not necessarily adapted to $(\mathcal F_t)$.

Then is there any well-known situation or fact by which we can ensure the existence of some filtration $(\mathcal G_t)$ with respect to which $(X_t)$ is adapted and still $\mathbb E(X_t\mid \mathcal G_{t-1}) = 0$ for every $t$?

That is, is there any special example or condition under which we can make a sequence or an array of random variables a martingale difference by changing(enlarging) the original filtration? My naive guess is that one could realize this by using the natural filtration of $(X_t)$ and the original filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$

Comment: The hypothesis says very little when $\mathcal F_t =\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ for all $t$. (It just says $X_t$ has mean $0$).  I think you are being over-ambitious.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murphy I agree.